# How to increase increase database attribute by one by making a get request to the database from Reactjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I am working on Mernstack. I have a model called Events, the Events have a title, description, startingDate, and closingDate attributes. when an Event is created, people can indicate that they are going for the event by clicking a button and this button will update another attribute inside that Event called `going` by increasing the number by 1. this was working with Node and Expressjs only but now that I am integrating React to Node, I don't know how to make it work.

Now my question is, how do I make a `GET` request from `React` to My Express route, by clicking a link so that the `going` attribute inside the Event model will be increased by one?

Here is my Event route

```
 router.get("/:id/going", async (req, res, next) => {
   Event.findById(req.params.id, function(err, event) {
      if (!event) {
       return next(new Error('Could not load Document'));
      }else {
      event.going += 1;
      event.save();
      res.json(event)
     }
   });
});
```

and here is my constructor in Reactjs.
Note: my Event and EventComment is working fine, i am only looking for a way to increase the value of going attribute inside the event by 1 whenever a link clicked.

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        eventcomments: [],
        event: '',
        name: '',
        description:'',
        going: '',

    };
}
```

the GET request i want to use to trigger the event route to increase the number by 1

```
 axios.get('http://localhost:9000/events/'+this.props.match.params.id+'/going')
    .then(res => {
        this.setState({
            going: '',
        })
    })
```

and this is the link i want a user to click for the going attribute in the Event route to increase by 1

```
<Link to={"/events/"+this.state.event._id+"/going"}>Going</Link>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks Guys. I have managed to get it to work.
Here is what I did.

```
  updateGoing = going => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:9000/events/'+this.props.match.params.id+'/going')
    .then(response => {
        his.setState({event: response.data})
});
```

and Changed it from Link to Button

```
<button onClick={() => this.updateGoing(this.state.event._id)}> Going </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

since your endpoint is returning the updated event record with the updated `going` property, just set state with that value.

```
axios.get('http://localhost:9000/events/'+this.props.match.params.id+'/going')
.then(res => {
    this.setState({
        going: res.data.going
    })
})
```

if `res.data.going` is how the return value is shaped.

Comment: Thank you @Splitty I will try it. the main issue is that when I click the link, the route does not get hit at all, i don't know why the link does not hit the route

Comment: oh I see what you're asking now.  the `<Link ... </>` element will navigate the user to the /going page.  Just have the going page use the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method or equivalent hook to trigger the `axios.get` call.